# how to fix openerp error "No such external ID currently defined in the system "

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have been working on an openerp 7 module . I have defined some fields and other features to this module . But when I try to install , it gives me the following error .

```
" ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: base.group_tool_manager "
```

. I( have no idea of how to deal with such problem . Plz help

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referencing the group `base.group_tool_manager` in your code or in a module you depend on. A quick search of my OpenERP 7 install shows this group is added by the subscription module so if you are going to use this group, you need to add a dependency to the subscription module in your module's `__openerp__.py` depends list.